# Ads making recyclerview lag

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I put banner ads from admob in my recyclerview and it lags my recyclerview when the user scrolls, here's my adapter code of the recyclerview I'm talking about. What could be wrong that it makes the recyclerview lag?

```
public class NewReleasesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter< RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {
    public static final String TAG = NewReleasesAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Release> mNewReleases;
    private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    // A game/release item view type.
    private static final int GAME_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;
    // The banner ad view type.
    private static final int BANNER_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;
    // Billing
    private BillingProcessor mBillingProcessor;
    private boolean mIsProVersion;
    // Ads
    private AdRequest mAdRequest;

    public NewReleasesAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        mDatabaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getDatabaseHelper(mContext);

        mBillingProcessor = new BillingProcessor(
                mContext,
                "...",
                this);
        mBillingProcessor.initialize();
        mBillingProcessor.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();

        // Is in europe
        if (ConsentInformation.getInstance(mContext).isRequestLocationInEeaOrUnknown()) {
            switch (ConsentInformation.getInstance(mContext).getConsentStatus()) {
                case PERSONALIZED:
                    // Personalized ads
                    mAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                    break;
                case NON_PERSONALIZED:
                    // fall though to none Personalized ads
                default:
                    // None Personalized ads
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    // npa is short for "none personalized ads"
                    extras.putString("npa", "1");
                    mAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                            .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
                            .build();
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            // Personalized ads
            mAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        }
    }

    public void setNewReleases(List<Release> newReleases) {
        this.mNewReleases = newReleases;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public  RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch(viewType) {
            case GAME_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                return new NewGameHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.newly_added_game, parent, false));
            case BANNER_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                return new ViewHolderAdMob(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_ad, parent, false), mAdRequest);
            default:
                return new NewGameHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.newly_added_game, parent, false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // isn't pro version
        if (mIsProVersion) {
            if ((position + 1) % 4 == 0) {
                return BANNER_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
            }
        }
        return GAME_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final  RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (viewType) {
            case BANNER_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                // nothing to do
                break;
            case GAME_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                // A lot of set texts
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mNewReleases == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return mNewReleases.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {
        // Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + errorCode + " : " + error.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingInitialized() {
        mBillingProcessor.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();
        if (mBillingProcessor.isPurchased("gaming_reminder_pro")) {
            mIsProVersion = true;
            // Toast.makeText(mContext, "You're a pro user! Thanks!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Show ads
            mIsProVersion = false;
        }
    }

    public BillingProcessor getBillingProcessor() {
        return mBillingProcessor;
    }

    public static class NewGameHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public TextView summary;
        public TextView releaseDate;
        public TextView platforms;
        public TextView genres;
        public ImageView cover;
        public Button favorite;
        public ProgressBar coverProgressBar;
        public RelativeLayout newReleaseLayout;

        public NewGameHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_name);
            summary = itemView.findViewById(R.id.summary);
            releaseDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.release_date);
            platforms = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platforms);
            genres = itemView.findViewById(R.id.genres);
            cover = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cover_image);
            favorite = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
            coverProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cover_progress_bar);
            newReleaseLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.new_release);
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolderAdMob extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public AdView mAdView;
        public ViewHolderAdMob(View view, final AdRequest adRequest) {
            super(view);
            mAdView = view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            if (adRequest != null) {
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
                mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some more helpful info: Generally, 4 banner ads are shown in this recyclerview and they are only shown for none-pro users. I have a pro iap (in app purchase) that removes the ads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to show native ads in a recycler view as it's more customizable in every way. If you must show banner ads, I'd suggest to preload the adviews in an activity or a fragment, then add or show them in the recycler view as needed. `ViewHolder` isn't a good place to load ads.

*You can follow this google provided example*

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/java/advanced/BannerRecyclerViewExample

Comment: Thank you brother, I will see this, but native ads got discontinued